# Creating a 3d coordinate system plus 3d vectors in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript, vector, 3d, coordinate-systems

I am just starting to dive into the world of 3D objects and perspectives, esp. in Flash.

My goal is to have a **3d coordinate system with grids** plus the option to define x, y, z values of a vector to be plotted.

Simple example: 
[image: 3d coordinate system with vector]

It would also be great to use the mouse to rotate the coordinate system, e. g. like in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GVaqm-4gfE) or [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylLR6gLRm-Y&NR=1).

Does anybody know if there is such a tool or library that provides such a 3d coordinate-system? I would prefer Flash AS2/AS3 but this is not a must-be. The only requirement: The tool must be running within the browser, no use of software such as Blender or SketchUp.

Maybe somebody has already written a program like that?

Thank you.

PS: I know that there are web services like [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector%20%7B1%2C%201%2C%201%7D) that can plot in 3d, but I need an interactive tool.

Comment: Just now I stumbled over a [away3d demo](http://polygeek.com/3896_away3d_101-view3d-and-camera3d) that shows a gridded coordinate systems which can be rotated.

Comment: Away3D is an excellent choice. PaperVision3D is no longer in development, so don't go with it.

Comment: The demo link I posted above is not working anymore. It moved to: http://polygeek.com/2011/04/18/101-coordinates/

Answer (score 0):

PaperVision3D is an opensource actionscript3 library that can handle all sorts of 3D rendering.  http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/ .  I've used it for programs that give you a full 3D environment with typical 6 degrees of freedom.